# Create a function that converts time to a binary response variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I currently have an RDD where I have two columns which are

```py
Row(pickup_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 14, 51)
   dropoff_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 14, 58)
```

I want to transform these into a binary response variable where 1 will indicate night time and 0 will indicate day time.

I know that we can use `UserDefinedFunction` to create a function where it would change these to the desired format.

For example I have another column which is a string which specifies payment type as either 'CSH' or 'CRD' so I am able to solve that doing this

```py
pay_map = {'CRD':1.0, 'CSH':0.0}
pay_bin = UserDefinedFunction(lambda z: pay_map[z], DoubleType())
df = df.withColumn('payment_type', pay_bin(df['payment_type']))
```

How would I apply this same logic to the question I am asking? If it helps I am trying to transform these variables since I will be running a decision tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for UDF here. You can use `between` and type casting:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import hour

def in_range(colname, lower_bound=6, upper_bound=17):
    """
    :param colname - Input column name (str)
    :lower_bound   - Lower bound for day hour (int, 0-23) 
    :upper_bound   - Upper bound for day hour (int, 0-23)
    """
    assert 0 <= lower_bound <= 23
    assert 0 <= upper_bound <= 23

    if lower_bound < upper_bound:
        return hour(colname).between(lower_bound, upper_bound).cast("integer")
    else:
        return (
            (hour(colname) >= lower_bound) |
            (hour(colname) <= upper_bound)
        ).cast("integer")
```

Example usage:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([
    Row(
        pickup_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 14, 51), 
        dropoff_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 14, 58)
    ),
    Row(
        pickup_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 19, 51), 
        dropoff_time=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 9, 1, 58)
    )
]).toDF()

(df
    .withColumn("dropoff_during_day", in_range("dropoff_time"))
    # between 6pm and 5am
    .withColumn("pickpup_during_night", in_range("pickup_time", 18, 5)))
```

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|        dropoff_time|         pickup_time|dropoff_during_day|pickpup_during_night|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|2014-02-09 14:58:...|2014-02-09 14:51:...|                 1|                   0|
|2014-02-09 01:58:...|2014-02-09 19:51:...|                 0|                   1|
+--------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```